# PHP cURL never runs any URL that's from my domain

Tags: php, eclipse, http, zend-framework, curl

The Problem:

I'm trying to have the front end of my website use the RESTful back end for getting information from my database. The PHP/cURL code I have down below works just fine for any URL other than https://mydomain.com[/anything], where mydomain is the domain I'm using and [/anything] is any sub-domain. It always just returns a header with http code 200 and an empty body, even if I call a URL full of broken code. But if I type the same URL into my web browser then I get the expected output (in most cases a JSON string).

So to recap:

If I call www.google.ca with my code, I get the XML that makes up www.google.ca. Good

If I call https:// mydomain.com/thing with my web browser, I get the expected JSON string that holds the information from the database. Excellent

If I call https:// mydomain.com/thing with my code, I get a header with no body that shows an http code of 200. Frustrating

Code (it's being called from indexAction from an AbstractActionController):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://mydomain.com/thing');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookieHeader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$err = curl_errno ( $ch );
$errmsg = curl_error ( $ch );
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo ( $ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE );

curl_close($ch);
```

What I'm using:

PHP5 with Zend Framework 2 in Ubuntu using the Eclipse dev environment

The https:// mydomain.com/thing points to an AbstractRESTfulController

**EDIT:**

It may be useful to know that I get these errors in the apache2 log after the cURL exec call:

[Zend Debugger] Cannot receive start command

[Zend Debugger] Cannot send message

Comment: Does a simple `file_get_contents` return the expected data locally?  Maybe its a hosts/DNS issue on your machine.  Have you tried it with removing the cookie or any other auth related code?

Comment: Since you are using `https` can you verify that your certificate is correct and valid? (self-signed certificates are typically _not_ valid).

Comment: @ficuscr It works, but I need the ability to do POSTs, DELETEs and PUTs as well. I also need to send information in the header.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the `CURLOPT_SSL` *should* address that.  OP: was not suggesting change, just trouble shooting.  It tells us a lot that `file_get_contents` worked.

Comment: @Frits van Campen My certificate is not valid, which is why I put the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to false.

Comment: Could it be due to the remote site checking for a user agent? Check your request headers and response headers in a normal browser window with firebug and try to match it for additional TS.

Comment: Header content length suggest that it is returning the body?  I'd want to believe the HTTP 200.  Your not doing something silly like trying to view the response in the browser and just missing it being there in the source view?

Comment: @ficuscr The Content-Length returned is 0.

Comment: @RobW I added the user-agent to my request header but it had no effect

Comment: Can you post more of what you're doing? Maybe something closer to what you're doing? The code above doesn't show how you're trying to dump the cURL results.

Comment: @RobW I'm not dumping the results anywhere yet. I'm just trying to make sure I can access them (by breaking and checking the values) before I continue any further

Comment: So I'm assuming you're `var_dump($response)` right?

Comment: @RobW No, I'm stopping at a break point and then stepping over the code and checking the values

Comment: I'm also assuming your controller's method is being called properly; assuming if using RESTful or RESOURCEful method names, it should be able to detect the GET properly?

Comment: At this point, if it's just a normal GET request, then I don't think your issue is on the CURL side of things, but probably the controller/router interpreting the request differently.

Comment: @RobW That's what I'm thinking, but the routers work fine when I type the URL in a web browser, so I don't know which part of the routing process is broken. I added some errors I found in the apache error logs in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this code actually works just fine, and the problem has to do with how my system authenticates.